# Insufficient rights to write a AD attribute after dsacls

Tags: permissions, active-directory

I have a problem with rights assignment in Active Directory. I want the "user1" from domain Example to be able to write and update an AD attribute of user accounts, the "mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid". I have assigned permissions through *dsacls* but I still get the error on the permission:

> Set-ADObject : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation

This is the result of the dsacls get on the OU that hosts the user account I am trying to modify

```
Inherited to account
Allow EXAMPLE\user1                   SPECIAL ACCESS for mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid   <Inherited from parent>
                                      WRITE PROPERTY
                                      READ PROPERTY
```

In most examples online I see "Inherited to user/group/computer" as category, but I don't know if this can be related to the error. 
Can you help me understand what I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which is the command you run?
I had the same problem, needed to change InheritedObjectType from account to user:

KO

```
dsacls "OU=xxxx,DC=dom1,DC=dom2" /I:S /g dom1\User1:WPRP; mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid;account
```

OK

```
dsacls "OU=xxxx,DC=dom1,DC=dom2" /I:S /g dom1\User1:WPRP; mS-DS-ConsistencyGuid;user
```